# How can I retain a local variable that is set in a completion block?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a function that takes an URL and returns a file URL asynchronously, when I print the value of `fileURL` inside the `completion` block it prints out perfectly, but the variable (`fileURL`) does not retain the value outside the `completion` block

```
FileFactory.FetchFileWithURL(workingURL, completionHandler: { (url) ->    Void in
            fileURL = url
            print(fileURL) //prints valid URLs

        })

print(fileURL) //prints nil
```

`fileURL` is defined as:- 
`var fileURL:String?`

How can I make sure, that `fireURL` retains the value it got from `completion`block?

EDIT:

Found similar question, but unfortunately it's in `objc` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347482/how-can-i-retain-a-local-variable-that-is-set-in-a-block)

Is there any equivalent of Objective-C's `__block` in swift

Comment: It cannot retain the value because at the moment the print line is executed the value isn't there yet. The fetched url is returned much later

Comment: Its quite simple. You need to wait for the completion block to execute, then the value `fileURL` will have a value, not before.

Comment: You don't need objc's __block, swift variables behave just like __block variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call a new function inside the block. Do what you want to do with `fileURL` inside the new method.

```
FileFactory.FetchFileWithURL(workingURL, completionHandler: { (url) ->    Void in
        fileURL = url
        print(fileURL) //prints valid URLs
        doSomethingWithFileUrl(url)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

`FetchWithURL` is an asynchronous function. `fileUrl` is instantiated in the `completionHandler` which itself is called only after the asynchronous task has been completed. Therefore, it simply isn't possible to use a value that doesn't exist yet.

Any operation that needs to be done with `fileUrl` must be done in the same `completionHandler`.

```
FileFactory.FetchFileWithURL(workingURL, completionHandler: { (url) ->    Void in
            fileURL = url
            print(fileURL) //prints valid URLs
            //other operations with fileURL
})
```