# drawRect Invalid Context

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect

Trying to draw a graph in `UIView` from values pulled down from a server.

I have a block that is successfully pulling the start/end points (I did have to add the delay to make sure the array had the values before commencing. I've tried moving the `CGContextRef` both inside and outside the dispatch but I still get 'Invalid Context'.

I have tried adding `[self setNeedsDisplay];` at various places without luck.

Here's the code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    // Drawing code

    // Array - accepts values from method
    float *values;

    UIColor * greenColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor * redColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];

    // Call to method to run server query, get data, parse (TBXML), assign values to array
    // this is working - NSLog output shows proper values are downloaded and parsed...
    values = [self downloadData];

    // Get context
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    NSLog (@"Context: %@", context);

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"Waiting for array to populate from URL/Parsing....");


    NSLog(@"length 1: %f", values[0]);
    NSLog(@"length 2: %f", values[1]);



    float starty = 100.0;
    float startleft = 25.0;

    CGContextSetLineWidth (context, 24.0);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor (context, greenColor.CGColor);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startleft, starty);

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, values[0], starty);

    NSLog(@"Start/Stop Win values: %f", values[0]);

    CGContextStrokePath (context);

    starty = starty + 24.0;


    CGContextSetLineWidth (context, 24.0);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor (context, redColor.CGColor);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startleft, starty);

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, values[1], starty);

    NSLog(@"Start/Stop Loss values: %f",  values[1]);

    CGContextStrokePath (context);

     */

    });

}
```

Comment: Below I’ve added a few observations, but I’m a little constrained in showing you what the solution should look like, because I’m having a hard time following what `downloadData` does. This code would suggest it’s just returning two `float` values. Is that really all your server is returning? Maybe a little more context about the nature of the server response and what you want rendered would be helpful...

Comment: I'm glad you answered - wanted to thank you for an answer to a question years ago where you laid out the 'get data in a method; pass array w values back to program' strategy - that got me this far.  This is just a simple example. Once I'm successful on this scene there will be 4; then have 8 more scenes that can have variable numbers of bars. The 2 sec was just arbitrary - I added it only to get the values[0] and [1] not to be =0.0. And I did try sync.

Comment: 1. Yep, we avoid these arbitrary times and do something a little more deterministic. 2. You’re making it really hard for any of us to provide a meaningful code snippets without some basic information about the nature of the structure of data being returned. We can help you better if we knew what the model data could contain...

Comment: I appreciate you at least trying - this isn't the 1st question - got many snotty SO responses. The downloadData sends a request to a server w a MySQL db; runs a query, sends back 4 XMLvalues that I want to parse/use on a horizontal bar graph. The user will be entering this scene by filling in 2 text fields on the main scene (which will be saved as user defaults to be reused from scene to scene) and pressing a button. Once they've viewed this scene pressing the Next button will run another query to create another scene with another bar/pie chart. And on and on...

Comment: PS - and the floats are numbers that I will do some 'pixel math' on to create the bar graphs that tell the story (also create labels w the values - that works) AND fit on an iPhone. I successfully did this with the deprecated URL calls - everything was in a single thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. This invalid context is a result that you’re initiating an asynchronous process, so by the time the `dispatch_after` block is called, the context supplied to `drawRect` no longer exists and your asynchronously called block has no context in which to stroke these lines.

   But the view shouldn’t be initiating this network request and parsing. Usually the view controller (or better, some other network controller or the like) should be initiating the network request and the parsing.
2. The `drawRect` is for rendering the view at a given moment in time. If there’s nothing to render yet, it should just return immediately. When the data is available, you supply the view the data necessary to do the rendering and initiate the `setNeedsDisplay`.
3. So, a common pattern would be to have a property in your view subclass, and have the setter for that property call `setNeedsDisplay` for you.
4. Rather than initiating the asynchronous request and trying to use the data in two seconds (or any arbitrary amount of time), you instead give your `downloadData` a completion handler block parameter, which it calls when the download is done, and trigger the updating immediately as soon as the download and parse is done. This avoids unnecessary delays (e.g. if you wait two seconds, but get data in 0.5 seconds, why wait longer than necessary; if you want two seconds, but get data in 2.1 seconds, you risk not having any data to show). Initiate the update of the view exactly when the download and parse is done.
5. This `float *` reference is a local variable and will never get populated. Your `downloadData` probably should return the necessary data in the aforementioned completion handler. Frankly, this notion of a pointer to a C array is not a pattern you should be using in Objective-C, anyway. If your network response really returns just two floats, that’s what you should be passing to this view, not a `float *`.
6. Note, I’ve replaced the CoreGraphics code with UIKit drawing. Personally, I’d be inclined to go further and move to `CAShapeLayer` and not have a `drawRect` at all. But I didn’t want to throw too much at you. But the general idea is to use the highest level of abstraction as you can and there’s no need to get into the weeds of CoreGraphics for something as simple as this.

---

This isn’t going to be quite right as I don’t really understand what your model data is, but let’s assume for a second it’s just returning a series of float values. So you might have something like:

```
//  BarView.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface BarView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, copy, nullable) NSArray <NSNumber *> *values;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

And

```
//  BarView.m

#import "BarView.h"

@implementation BarView
    
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if (!self.values) { return; }

    NSArray *colors = @[UIColor.greenColor, UIColor.redColor]; // we’re just alternating between red and green, but do whatever you want

    float y = 100.0;
    float x = 25.0;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.values.count; i++) {
        float value = [self.values[i] floatValue];
        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        path.lineWidth = 24;
        [colors[i % colors.count] setStroke];
        [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)];
        [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + value, y)];
        [path stroke];

        y += 24;
    }
}

- (void)setValues:(NSArray<NSNumber *> *)values {
    _values = [values copy];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
@end
```

Note, this isn’t doing any network requests. It’s just rendering whatever values have been supplied to it. And the setter for `values` will trigger `setNeedsDisplay` for us.

Then

```
//  ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (void)download:(void (^)(NSArray <NSNumber *> * _Nullable, NSError * _Nullable))completion;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

And

```
//  ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "BarView.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet BarView *barView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self download:^(NSArray <NSNumber *> *values, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
            return;
        }

        self.barView.values = values;
    }];
}

- (void)download:(void (^)(NSArray <NSNumber *> *, NSError *))completion {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"..."];
    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        // parse the data here

        if (error) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                completion(nil, error);
            });
            return;
        }

        NSArray *values = ...

        // when done, call the completion handler
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completion(values, nil);
        });
    }] resume];
}

@end
```

Now, I’ll leave it up to you to build the `NSArray` of `NSNumber` values, as that’s a completely separate question. And while moving this network/parsing code out of the view and into the view controller is a little better, it probably doesn’t even belong there. You might have another object dedicated to performing network requests and/or parsing results. But, again, that’s probably beyond the scope of this question.

But hopefully this illustrates the idea: Get the view out of the business of performing network requests or parsing data. Have it just render whatever data was supplied.

That yields:

[image]

Comment: Your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347482/how-can-i-retain-a-local-variable-that-is-set-in-a-block/ is what lead me to this strategy and is closer to the goal line than I've been.

Comment: Lol. That’s a crazy old answer. See revised answer above with some code snippets (but the basic ideas of asynchronous requests, completion handlers, etc., still apply).

Comment: Your old answer stands up to the test of time - esp since Obj-c is fading out - tougher and tougher to find info as Swift rules. Thanks for the new answer - accepted. That will get me over the hump. I get the concept now. I'll have a bunch of the download methods - think of my app as a series of Key Performance Indicators (KPI's) that a user will scroll/swipe through.